# Opening shapefile in OpenWind

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, openwind

In QGIS I have used the OpenLayers plugin to locate a wind farm. I have then used the add feature function to place a point at the base of 7 turbines. I have saved the shapefile as an ESRI shapefile.

I am trying to open this shapefile in OpenWind but am getting back the following errors:

"failed to open file"
"Problem reading SHX file - aborting Shape.Read()"
"error loading vector layer"

Comment: Did you load the .shx file or the .shp file?

Comment: When I click Open Vector Layer, the only files that are visible are .shp files

Comment: I have just installed OpenWind and successfully loaded a point vector layer. Can you open the vector layer again in QGIS and are the points still there?

Comment: I have just opened the layer again in QGIS and the feature points are missing. I must be saving the layer incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right Will, you have to save the features **first** before you can save it as a shapefile. When you toggle the editing icon to add your points, toggle it again. You should see a message come up:

[image: Toggle editing]

[image: Save message]

(Alternatively if you have the layer's attribute table loaded, you can save the features by clicking on the **save** icon).

Now you should be able to load the shapefile into openWind. Here is my point layer in QGIS:

[image: Point layer in QGIS]

And here it is again in openWind:

[image: Point layer in openWind]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that's very helpful! For some reason, my shape file and digital elevation model are not aligned in OpenWind. Im guessing this has something to do with the CRS but I am struggling to get them aligned. I have created another question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118301/digital-elevation-model-and-shapefile-not-aligned-in-openwind

Comment: Most welcome buddy! Yes, I believe you may be right about a mismatch with the CRS. The answers to the question you posted should hopefully solve your problem: in QGIS, disable `on-the-fly`; save your vector with a certain CRS; _warp (reproject)_ your DEM to the same CRS.