# Digital Elevation Model and Shapefile not aligned in openWind

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, dem, openwind

I have a digital elevation model and a shapefile containing point features for the location of wind turbines. These two layers appear to be aligned in QGIS but when I open them in openWind, they are not aligned.

I am guessing this has something to do with CRS but I am unsure how to align these layers?

Answer (score 2):

I find openWind normally works very well so, without any further information, I suspect you are spot on about mismatched CRS.  According to the documentation:

> openWind is fundamentally based on a meter grid so the projection only
>   comes into play when converting to and from geographic coordinates.
>   openWind does not carry out on-the-fly projection so it is important
>   not to mix GIS data from one mapping datum with data from another.

Check what CRS your layers are in using the layer properties in QGIS and then export one or both layers as required in the same CRS (not WGS84).  For the Vector layer it is as simple as right-clicking your layer and choosing `Save As`.  In the dialog box, set the output CRS.  For your raster go Raster->Projections->Warp and you can set the Target SRS in the dialog box there.

Answer (score 2):

You might see both datasets aligned because `On-the-fly-reprojection` is enabled. This works when both datasets have different CRS.

Other software does not offer this tool, so you have to reproject one of your datasets to the CRS of the other to make them align in every software.

BTW this applies also to some tools integrated in QGIS, like intersection or clipper tools.